# Getting error-highlighting on things like `Object.assign` and `Promise<any>`

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Hi I'm having problems supporting the "lib" property in `tsconfig` when using WebStorm 2016.2.2.

I've tried editing the TypeScript version in the IDE preferences (`Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript`) and pointing to a globally-installed TypeScript 2.0 version, but I'm still getting error-highlighting on things like `Object.assign` and `Promise<any>`.

I've restarted the IDE multiple times, and nothing seems to change, any ideas on how to fix or debug this?

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
        "core": ["app/core"],
        "reactive": ["app/reactive"],
        "models": ["app/models"],
        "services": ["app/services"]
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "protractor",
      "selenium-webdriver",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Comment: You specified `"target": "es5"` so the compiler will compile it with the regular [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts) and not the [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts) and so those definitions are missing. Change it to `"target": "es6"` and it should be fine.

Comment: Note that TS doesn't provide any polyfill on its own, in case you're targetting browsers that don't support ES6.

Comment: @NitzanTomer can you post this as an answer so I can mark you correct? thank you :)

Stijn - yeh, I'm using core-js for those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specified:

```
"target": "es5"
```

So the compiler will compile it with the regular [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts) and not the [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts) and so `ES6` features such as `Object.assign` and `Promise` and others are missing.

Change it to

```
"target": "es6"
```

and it should be fine.